# Convergence of measures concentrated on graphs of functions

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose we have a sequnece of probability measures $\{ \mu_n\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{d+m}$ where each element is concentrated on the graph of a function, that is $\mu_n$ is concentrated on $\{ (x,f_n(x)) :\; x \in \mathbb{R}^d\}|$ for some function $f_n : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^m$.

Suppose that $\mu_n$ coverges weakly to $\mu$. Can we say that $\mu$ is also concentrated on the graph of a function? Does the answer change if we assume that the range of all $f_n$ is restricted to some finite set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The arclength measure on the graph of $y=x^n$, $0\le x\le 1$, converges weakly to the arclength measure on the union of line segments from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ and then to $(1,1)$. The latter set is not a graph.

The answer is still negative if every $f_n$ takes values in the same finite set. Let $f_n$ be the $n$th Rademacher function, that is, $f_n(x)=\operatorname{sign}\sin (2\pi\cdot 2^n x) $ for $x\in [0,1]$. Let $\mu_n$ be the pushforward of the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ under $f_n$. Then the weak limit of $\mu_n$ is the average of linear Lebesgue measure on line segments $I_+=\{(x,1):0\le x\le 1\}$ and $I_-=\{(x,-1):0\le x\le 1\}$. Hence, the support of the limit is $I_+\cup I_-$, which is not a graph.

What you can infer about  the support of $\mu$ is that it's contained in the closure of  $\bigcup \operatorname{supp}\mu_n$. Indeed, if $U$ is an open set on which each $\mu_n$ is zero, then every continuous function with support in $U$ integrates to zero againste every $\mu_n$, and therefore against $\mu$. It follows that $U\subseteq (\operatorname{supp}\mu)^c$.

Comment: Thanks for the nice examples. I was wondering how you show that, say, the first example converges to that limit. (I can see it based on the Wasserstein distance, which seems to be the easiest way?) Also, not to be pedantic, but in the second example you probably meant that $\mu_n$ is the pushforward under $(id,f_n)$, with $id$ being the identity map.